# activate and positioning a slider price range of booking form

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Please, help me to activate a slider price range of the booking form. Also, I would like to know how can I reposition it.

Could you please check the [link](https://codepen.io/artyom14/project/editor/AqjpLJ#) I have attached

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/artyom14/project/editor/AqjpLJ#
```

Comment: What you mean by *acivate*?

Comment: When a user made a choice of the booking options the slider would display a price range for a night in the hotel